Memoir epihead command discards footer
I'm trying to use the memoir class for a document, but I can't add an epigraph in the header using epihead, as that discards a required footer
Is this command changing the style, I've seen \thispagestyle in epihead returns epigraph, but changing that style does not help
(I need a footer on all pages, if you know a solution that works for memoir, I'd be happy to hear, I currently redefine lots of style)
I've tracked the issue to
epigraphhead doing
\ps@epigraph:->\let \@mkboth \@gobbletwo \@epipos \if@epirhs \def \@oddhead {\hfil \begin {picture}(
0,0) \put (0,-95){\makebox (0,0)[r]{\@epitemp }} \end {picture}} \else \if@epicenter \def \@oddhead
{\hfil \begin {picture}(0,0) \put (0,-95){\makebox (0,0)[b]{\@epitemp }} \end {picture}\hfil
} \else \def \@oddhead {\begin {picture}(0,0) \put (0,-95){\makebox (0,0)[l]{\@epitemp }} \end
{picture}\hfil } \fi \fi \let \@evenhead \@oddhead \def \@oddfoot {\reset@font \hfil \thepage \hfil
} \let \@evenfoot \@oddfoot

Especially the last part.
MWE coming soon

AFAIK usually there is a footer with the page number. Maybe this is not the footer you want. So please show a minimal working example that illustrates your needs and your problem. Maybe use that example to explicitly tell us, how the footer should be changed. This would help us not only to understand your problem but also to find a solution.
